# PySide6 setupUi TypeError

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget, pyside6

I'm trying to run the following Code:

```
import PySide6
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from frm_main import Ui_frm_main

class Frm_main(QMainWindow, Ui_frm_main):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

app = QApplication()
frm_main = Frm_main()
frm_main.show()
app.exec()
```

but I get this error:

```
File "c:\Python Projects\PyQt Test\frm_main.py", 
line 18, in setupUi
     self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(frm_main)
TypeError: QWidget(parent: QWidget = None, flags: 
Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = 
Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 
'Frm_main'
```

I used pyuic5 to create the frm_main.py file from a .ui file.

Comment: Did you create the ui file with pyuic or pyside-uic? PyQt and PySide cannot be used together. If you want to use PySide, you need to create the ui file with pyside-uic, and vice versa. You can also switch the import statement in the generated python file, but you have to remember that anyway in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much. I created the ui file with pyuic because converting it with pyside-uic gave me another error but changing the import statement fixed the problem.

Comment: Please explain what error was given and consider submitting a bug report.

Comment: I agree with @musicamante - you should not change import statements in python files generated by `uic` normally. It is either a mistake or a bug.

Comment: I figured out that my antivirus program blocked pyside6-uic but now after deactivating it I can convert using the pyside uic and Im not getting any errors anymore.